# Unable to get log.d or output Robolectrict + gradle

Tags: android, unit-testing, output, robolectric

Has anyone being able to output System.out or Log.d traces from robolectric test  to gradle console. I am using [Robolectric Gradle test plugin](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric-gradle-plugin) I use the console to run my test since it is more painful to try to run it in AS, anyway I was trying to output the my test classes but unable to get them I've try from ShadowLog.stream=stdout to robolectric.logging in gradle file, and nothing . Has anyone able to achieve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you run test in Android Studio terminal you can do that. First you have to implement @Before:

```
    @Before
    public void init() { 
        ShadowLog.stream = System.out;
    }
```

Next run your tests with --info parameter, like:

```
    gradlew library:test --info
```

You will be able to use:

```
    System.out.println("test");
    ShadowLog.i("Serialization", "test");
    Log.i("Serialization", "test");
```