# How to turn on robolectric logging

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

I need a very simple way to get Robolectric 3.0 to turn on logging. I want to see the output from robolectric, not just my tests. Everything I tried off the web is not working.

Where do I stick this?

```
robolectric.logging.enabled = true
```

**I tried the following:**

In a robolectric.properties file in test/java/res

In a robolectric.properties file in test/java/resources

In a robolectric.properties file in test/res

In a robolectric.properties file in test/resources

In gradle:

```
afterEvaluate {
    project.tasks.withType(Test) {
        systemProperties.put('robolectric.logging.enable', 'true')
    }
}
```

In gradle:

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
    testLogging.exceptionFormat = 'full'
    systemProperties.put('robolectric.logging.enable', 'true')
}
```

Comment: When you mean "logging" what are you expecting to see? The output of the tests?

Comment: I'll edit the question. I want to see what robolectric is doing. I want to know what ContextImpl.ensureDirsExistOrFilter() does under the hood.

Comment: What is the status on this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### You can add to your tests:

```
@Before
public void init() { 
    ShadowLog.stream = System.out;
}
```

then use: `gradle test -i`

Source: [Unable to get log.d or output Robolectrict + gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25005667/unable-to-get-log-d-or-output-robolectrict-gradle)

### or Add in the `build.gradle`:

```
tasks.withType(Test) { 
     systemProperty "robolectric.logging", "stdout" 
}
```

Source: https://github.com/studyplus/Studyplus-Android-SDK/blob/master/StudyplusAndroidSDK/build.gradle#L41

Comment: For a little more clarification: ShadowLog.stream = System.out, only logs my tests but the gradle addition logged everything, robolectric material and my personal test material.

Comment: Great! Thanks for your confirmation.

Comment: Only the first option with the ShadowLog works for me. With this added I get  logging output from all my Log statements in the app printed to the terminal.

Comment: What about this question ? Can you please help me with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35726314/configure-robolectric-to-write-logs-into-external-file

Comment: Is the build.gradle suggestion valid for Roboelectric 3.0 with Gradle 2? When I try this, it doesn't work and Android Studio warn that it can not resolve 'systemProperty'

Comment: Yes to both. The latest version of Gradle is 2.12.

Comment: Thanks @JaredBurrows. Android Studio v2 complains: "Can not resolve symbol 'systemProperty'". I was compared my build.gradle to your example but you use Roboelectric 2.4 and the 'robolectric' plugin, which is [deprecated](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric-gradle-plugin) now. Do you have an updated example?

Comment: @sidecarcat Use `gradlew` via command line. Do not rely on Android Studio. What version of gradle are you using? That is not my example. See `Test` and `systemProperty` here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html.

Comment: only the first option works with robolectric 3.1.2 (the `systemProperty` has no effect)