# configure Robolectric to write logs (tests output) into external file

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, robolectric, android-testing

I'm adding the following code to `build.gradle` :

```
android{
    testOptions {
        unitTests.all {
            systemProperty 'robolectric.logging', '/path/to/file/robolectric.log'
            systemProperty 'robolectric.logging.enabled', 'true'
        }
    }
}
```

The file `/path/to/file/robolectric.log` has 777 permissions.

The `robolectric.logging.enabled=true` is working because I started to see the output when I had configured with `robolectric.logging=stdout` ([like here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31885348/1081827))

Questions:

1) How to configure Robolectric to write the output into a file ? 
2) How to configure Robolectric to write the output into something like `build/output/robolectric.log`? The test cases are executed by Jenkins and I would like to have the option to have the robotic logging for each execution.

Comment: Are you just talking about a text file log? I mean it creates .xml files for the tests results and a .html page already.

Comment: I'm talking about text file log. A file with the complete Robolectric execution logs.

Comment: Unless you write something yourself, there is nothing. Please see this: http://willis7.github.io/blog/2013/gradle-output-to-log.html.